# Why are two datetimes of different formats not equal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, datetime, logical-operators, equality

I'm running Matlab R2014b. I have two datetime variables in that in my mind should be equivalent, what is causing the logical equals to return FALSE here?

```
testDate = textscan('20171231', '%{yyyymmdd}D')
myDate = testDate{1,1}
myDate == datetime(2017,12,31)
```

This returns:

```
ans = 0
```

Comment: Month is `'MM'`. `'mm'` is minutes. See: [`datetime`'s format specification](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#buhzxmk-1-Format)

Comment: Thanks for this. What confused is that elsewhere in my code I'm calling the datestr function which expects 'mm' as month. This seems like a pretty rough inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As excaza mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267221/why-are-two-datetimes-of-different-formats-not-equal-in-matlab/51267438#comment89512843_51267221), you have to use `'MM'` to correctly represent *months* instead of *minutes* in the call to [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
>> testDate = textscan('20171231', '%{yyyyMMdd}D');
>> myDate = testDate{1,1};
>> myDate == datetime(2017,12,31)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#buhzxmk-1-Format) for more information on the `datetime` Format property.

Comment: Thanks for this. What confused is that elsewhere in my code I'm calling the datestr function which expects 'mm' as month. This seems like a pretty rough inconsistency?

Comment: @Trojanian: Yeah, that's an annoying one. I'm guessing they haven't changed it for backwards compatibility issues, because it's the behavior people have come to expect for each function. But I would still rather they bite the bullet and change it.